# How to check word in file with list element by using index?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of words in two files. I want to check the word from file 2 with file 1. The word that match will replace by 1. If have duplicate word then number of them will be count and used instead of 1. If not match then 0 will be used. They will used the same row format as in file 1. 
(sorry about my explanation)

```
file 1: a,b,c,1,5,9,12

file 2: a 1 c 12
        c 9 a b
        5 b 5 c
        9 12 a b
```

I tried the code below but I still lost as I got all 0. Any suggestion?

```
        header = []
        for line in open(file1):
            lines = line.strip().split(',')
            for i,j in enumerate(lines):
                header.append(j)
            #print header
        for line in open(file2):
            linesMo = line.strip().split()
            for words in linesMo:
                if words != j:
                    print '0',
                if words == j:
                    print '1',
```

I want the results to be:

```
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1     # a 1 c 12
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0     # c 9 a b
0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0     # 5 b 5 c
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1     # 9 12 a b
```

Comment: And what result do you get now?

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be `1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I did by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("Input1.txt") as in_file1, open("Input2.txt") as in_file2:
    line = next(in_file1).rstrip().split(",")
    for row in map(str.split, in_file2):
        print [row.count(item) for item in line]
```

**Output**

```
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

You can do it even more efficiently, like this

```
from collections import Counter
with open("Input1.txt") as in_file1, open("Input2.txt") as in_file2:
    line = next(in_file1).rstrip().split(",")
    for row in map(str.split, in_file2):
        print map(Counter(row).__getitem__, line)
```